# @EJB Annotation doesn't work in Servlet

Tags: servlets, ejb-3.0, jndi, websphere-7, myeclipse

I'm using Websphere 7.0 Application Server and want to use `@EJB` - annotations in a LoginServlet. When I deploy the application directly over MyEclipse (BlueEdition 8.6) everything works fine and the annotations are resolved.

But when I create an EAR-File by using the export function in MyEclipse and deploy it manually on Websphere-Server, the `@EJB` annotations are not resolved and so I get a `NullpointerException` when accessing the reference.

Then I tried jndi-lookup in the doGet-method of the Servlet instead of the @ejb-annotations and everything worked fine, also when I put the lookup into the init-method. But when deploying manually on Websphere the jndi-lookup doesn't work in the init-method.

Do you have any ideas where there is a difference between the myEclipse-Deploying and the ear-deploying manually so that it only works with myEclipse-Deploying?

Comment: It'd be good to see the structure of the two ear files. One possibility could be that any of the ejb jar modules are not located in the root of your ear but in the /lib folder, and therefore they are not recognized as ejb modules?

Comment: the structure of the exported .ear-File looks like:
- target
- META-INF
- lib
- ZWRWEB.war
- ZWRService.jar
- pom.xml

the structure of the eclipse-deployed ear folders is:
- target
- META-INF
- lib
- ZWRService.jar (already unpacked - as a folder)
- ZWRWeb.war (already unpacked - as a folder)
- pom.xml

what i found out is, that there is a web_merged.xml File in the WEB-INF-Folder of ZWRWeb.war-Folder in the Eclipse-deployed-Ear-Folder